# What happen to code highlight?

Tags: discussion

The code highlight seems to change its theme, which make it very hard to distinguish between `comment`, `string`, `normal text`.

Did I break some setting in my browser? Or it is intend to change the theme?

If it is intended, why? Can we make it more distinguishable between those type?

[image]

```
test = {
    "string": "Run specified script in all context",
    "variable": desc,
    "module": bpy,
    "tuple": (0, 1, 0),
    "list": [2, 80, 0],
    "float": 3.14159,
    "comment": ""  # code highlight
}
```

Comment: Here on meta there doesn't seem to be any active code highlighting, as far as I can tell. On main it is working as intended for me on your second example. It isn't immediate thought, it takes a few seconds to "kick in".

Comment: Also this [update from Prettify to Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983) went through, so you might have caught some maintenance off time or during transition period

Comment: Yes, can confirm it is a temporary change and now string colored as dark green.